# How fallback cmd parameter to environment variable to defaul valune in serverless?

Tags: serverless-framework

Consider exmaple:

```
stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
```

If `--stage` parameter is not pass `dev` value will be used.

```
stage: ${opt:stage, ${env.STAGE, 'dev'}}
```

Leads to error because `stage` value is not a string

```
stage: ${opt:stage, "${env.STAGE, 'dev'}"}
```

Resolves to `dev` even if I set `STAGE` system variable.

So is there a way to make the following logic:
1. if `STAGE` system variable is present - it should be used
1. if `--stage`  parameter is present - it should be used. (overrides `STAGE` system variable if both are present)
1. when no parameter or system variable are provided default `dev` is used

How to define variables to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last effort is so very close.  You want `env:STAGE`, instead of `env.STAGE`.

`stage: ${opt:stage, "${env:STAGE, 'dev'}"}`

More on environment variables in *Serverless* [here](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables#referencing-environment-variables).